# How to integrate search functionality on the map filtering information in the data table?

Tags: search

I want to a site with the same functionality just like AZAVEA created the energy station with search functionality

http://www.afdc.energy.gov/locator/stations/results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&location=&filtered=true&fuel=E85&owner=all&payment=all&ev_level1=true&ev_level2=true&ev_dc_fast=true&radius_miles=5

Comment: You may need to provide additional information. What is your existing database and online map technology? What queries have you tried for filtering so far?